# ASP.Net Web Form - Trying to duplicate table in the .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a table which looks as below. The data is populating correctly for one class object.

[image]

What I am trying to do is create 5 lots of this table, and apart from the table name, have everything else the same. So I somehow need have the label names in a loop so that multiple  objects can populate

lblDescription[0]

lblDescription[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6N6O.png)

And same with the other labels.

Here is my C# code which is populating the single table currently.

```
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        WeatherInfo weatherinfo = serializer.Deserialize<WeatherInfo>(json);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (List list in weatherinfo.list)
        {
            lblCity_Country.Text = weatherinfo.city.name;
            //lblDescription.Text = weatherinfo.list[0].weather[0].description;

            lblTempMin.Text = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_min, 1));
            lblTempMax.Text = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_max, 1));

            lblHumidity.Text = weatherinfo.list[i].main.humidity.ToString();
            tblWeather.Visible = true;



            i++;
        }
```

So each list object is populating one table. But I need to have my table configuration set up dynamically, that that it can work for any number of 'list' objects.

I hope I have explained this well,

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: You can construct & bind data in <tr> <td> to display. Check repeater, datalist also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Controls. According to your question, I recommend Reapter.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is a sample designed for your conditions.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_weatherReports" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Weather Info
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_city" Text='<%# Eval("city.name") %>' />&nbsp;
                    humidity:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_humidity" Text='<%# Eval("main.humidity") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    min:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_min" Text='<%# Eval("main.temp_min") %>' />
                    max:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_max" Text='<%# Eval("main.temp_max") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then at the code behind you can simply just assign your list to the Repeater

```
Repeater_weatherReports.DataSource = weatherinfo.list;
Repeater_weatherReports.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only issue I have is with the new label names for some reason, my .cs file cannot see the label IDs from the .aspx file.

Before i could use <label_name>.Text in my .cs file, but now the label ID names are not recognised. Any idea  why this is?